# What is the difference between using `:plain` vs `:login` in active mailer smtp settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smtp, actionmailer

What is the difference between using `:plain` vs `:login` in active mailer smtp settings as authentication ?

**PLAIN**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

**LOGIN**

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
        :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
        :port           => '587',
        :authentication => :login,
        :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
        :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
        :domain         => 'heroku.com',
        :enable_starttls_auto => true
      }
```

In different tutorial about configuring smpt setting especially for send-grid i have seen these  been used.

both of them seems to be be working, so what is the difference between these two? 
and which one is recommended and why ?

I headed `:plain` use `base64` encoding to obfusticate the credentials, so is that the safest one ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short as you are using **TLS** your credentials are safe as they are being exchanged on an encrypted connection.

According to ActionMailer documentation [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#class-ActionMailer::Base-label-Configuration+options) irrespective of authentication `:plain` or `:login` the password is always `Base64` encoded. The problem with `Base64` encoding is that it can be easily decoded by anybody eavesdropping in on the SMTP communication. So both of these authentication mechanisms are really the same in terms of security.

However as you are using `TLS` the connection is encrypted and the Base64 credentials are sent over this encrypted connection making it secure. If you were not using TLS then it would be better to use `:cram_md5` instead of `:login` or `:plain` to secure the credentials.

Comment: This answer is correct but incomplete since OP also asked the difference between PLAIN and LOGIN : PLAIN sends both login and password in the same Base64-encoded string, whereas LOGIN sends them separately.